# jsf 2.0 response already commented (ajax)

Tags: ajax, events, jsf, listener, response

overflow,

since yesterday I have for unknown reasons following problem:

i have a list of items, and when i delete one of them and let the page refresh by ajax, it stucks after the deletion-procedure and prints me following error:

Jul 28, 2013 3:54:42 PM org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl setResponseContentType
**SEVERE: Cannot set content type. Response already committed**

the deletion code is called by:

```
public void deleteEntry(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){...} //runs fine
```

and the ajax part is:

```
<h:commandButton value="delete" onclick="closeDialog(deleteDlg);">
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render=":maintable" listener="#{updateEntryMetaDataBean.deleteEntry}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

i don't really know why this error occurs, it seems like it only occurs on this specific page, on other pages with the same behaviour it runs fine.

my ajax-status hangs up and keeps running too:

```
    <!-- AJAX-STATUS INFO --> 
    <p:ajaxStatus style="width:64px;height:64px;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px">  
        <f:facet name="start">
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/loading.gif" />  
        </f:facet>   

        <f:facet name="complete">  
            <h:outputText value="" />  
        </f:facet>  
    </p:ajaxStatus>
```

what can I do there?

Comment: Having the entire stack trace is helpful in order to understand how the problem is caused.

Comment: There is no detailed stack trace; that is what my console writes:

(system.out.... outputs of the delete method)FETCH PARAMS
Jul 28, 2013 4:16:36 PM org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl setResponseContentType
SEVERE: Cannot set content type. Response already committed

I'm running it on tomcat if it helps

Comment: it executes the listener, but when trying to update the maintable, it throws this error. I need to reload the page and then i can continue... so it has to be a problem with ajax?

Comment: crazy stuff... after 20minutes of desperate testing and analysing, it works again... didn't change anything?? is there a server problem?

Comment: I really miss the "Too localized" close reason. I suggest to just delete this question as nobody else would face this problem in a normal circumstance.